# How to refactor methods with different List<Objects>

Tags: java

I faced with the problem of duplicated code and don't know how it should be solved.
I have 2 almost similar methods and in future I know that will be created more.

```
 public static List<ExamResult> numberOfMarks(List<ExamResult> allMarks, int offset, int records) throws DaoException {
    List<ExamResult> result = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < allMarks.size(); i++) {
        if (offset == 0) {
            if (i < records) {
                result.add(allMarks.get(i));

            }
        } else if (offset > 0) {
            if (i > offset * records && i < (offset * records + records + 1)) {
                result.add(allMarks.get(i));
            }

        }
    }
    return result;

}

public static List<Question> numberOfQuestions(List<Question> allQuestion, int offset, int records) throws DaoException {
    List<Question> result = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < allQuestion.size(); i++) {
        if (offset == 0) {
            if (i < records) {
                result.add(allQuestion.get(i));

            }
        } else if (offset > 0) {
            if (i > offset * records && i < (offset * records + records + 1)) {
                result.add(allQuestion.get(i));
            }

        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: generics could help as well

Comment: you can remove diamond operator and cast your list afterwards

Answer (score 4):

You can use "[generic methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/methods.html)". The method will be then :

```
public static <T> List<T> extract(List<T> input, int offset, int record) {
    ... //the same code with T instead of Question or Answer
}
```

Comment: When going down the road of defining generic methods one should also think about which requirements a parameter needs to actually fullfil. `Iterable<T>` should do here. Picking the interface which accomplishes this enables you to commit to a specific implementation as late as possible.

Comment: The thing is here it seems that the order the elements are picked is important. An iterable does not imply ordering.

Comment: I'm sorry. You' re right. I should've taken a look at the implemetation.

Answer (score 1):

'Generics' is the answer. Following is a working method.

```
public <T> List<T> numberOfQuestions(List<T> allItems, int offset, int records) {
    List<T> result = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < allItems.size(); i++) {
        if (offset == 0) {
            if (i < records) {
                result.add(allItems.get(i));

            }
        } else if (offset > 0) {
            if (i > offset * records && i < (offset * records + records + 1)) {
                result.add(allItems.get(i));
            }

        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use method [`List#subList(int fromIndex, int toIndex)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/List.html#subList(int,int)) to achieve what you want:

```
public static <T> List<T> getEntries(
    List<T> list,
    final int offset, 
    final int records) {
  final int listSize = list.size();

  final int fromIndex;
  if (offset == 0) {
    fromIndex = 0;
  } else if (offset * records + 1  < listSize) {
    fromIndex = offset * records + 1;
  } else {
    fromIndex = -1;
  }     

  final int toIndex;
  if (offset + records <= listSize) {
    toIndex = offset + records;
  } else {
    toIndex = listSize;
  }

  final List<T> result;
  if (fromIndex >= 0) {
    result = list.subList(fromIndex, toIndex);
  } else {
    result = Collections.emptyList(); // or new ArrayList<T>() if you want to modify the list
  }

  return result;
}

public static List<ExamResult> numberOfMarks(
    List<ExamResult> allMarks,
    final int offset,
    final int records) throws DaoException {
  return getEntries(allMarks, offset, records);
}

public static List<Question> numberOfQuestions(
    List<Question> allQuestions, 
    final int offset,
    final int records) throws DaoException {
  return getEntries(allQuestions, offset, records);
}
```